# Unable to run basic hello_world.ts file after fresh typescript installation WSL

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get started with Typescript.

I've followed the official 5min tutorial : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

```
npm install -g typescript
```

It was obviously too easy to be true. After some research on SO I've made progress with those commands :

```
➜  test_typescript npm config get prefix bin
/home/amehmeto/.npm-new
➜  test_typescript export PATH=/home/amehmeto/.npm-new/bin:$PATH
➜  test_typescript tsc -v
Version 3.7.2
➜  test_typescript tsc hello.ts
➜  test_typescript cat hello.ts
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

let user = "Jane User";

document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
➜  test_typescript node hello.ts
/mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/test_typescript/hello.ts:7
document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/test_typescript/hello.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11
➜  test_typescript vim hello.ts
➜  test_typescript tsc hello.ts
➜  test_typescript node hello.ts
Hello, Jane User
```

I changed the last line of `hello.ts` to be `console.log(greeter(user));`.

So it's working with the `node` command, which I understand because the script is pure javascript. But tsc desperately stays silent.

Comment: tsc staying silent means there were no errors or warnings and it worked. You should use `hello.js` after compilation though.

Comment: "But tsc desperately stays silent." --- what do you expect it to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I haven't read enough of that tutorial and expected tsc to be an equivalent of node. No, it just compile, do it well and do it only.